# Explanation of numpy indexing ndarray[(4, 2), (5, 3)]

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-indexing

## Question

Please help understand the design decision or rational of the Numpy indexing with tuple (i, j) into a ndarray.

### Background

When the index is a single tuple (4, 2), then (i=row, j=column).

```
shape = (6, 7)
X = np.zeros(shape, dtype=int)
X[(4, 2)] = 1
X[(5, 3)] = 1
print("X is :\n{}\n".format(X))
---
X is :
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]    <--- (4, 2)
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]   <--- (5, 3)
```

However, when the indices are multiple tuples (4, 2), (5, 3), then (i=row, j=row) for (4, 2) and (i=column, j=column) for (5, 3).

```
shape = (6, 7)
Y = np.zeros(shape, dtype=int)
Y[(4, 2), (5, 3)] = 1
print("Y is :\n{}\n".format(Y))
---
Y is :
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]    <--- (2, 3)
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0]    <--- (4, 5)
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

- [Numpy fancy indexing with 2D array - explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633219/numpy-fancy-indexing-with-2d-array-explanation)

> It means you are constructing a 2d array *R*, such that `R=A[B, C]`.
> This means that the value for
> *r<sub>ij</sub>=a<sub>b<sub>ij</sub>c<sub>ij</sub></sub>*.
>
> So it means that the item located at `R[0,0]` is the item in `A` with
> as row index `B[0,0]` and as column index `C[0,0]`. The item `R[0,1]`
> is the item in `A` with row index `B[0,1]` and as column index
> `C[0,1]`, etc.

- [numpy.ravel_multi_index(multi_index, dims, mode='raise', order='C')](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html)

> multi_index: A tuple of integer arrays, **one array for each dimension**.

Why not always (i=row, j=column)? What will happen if it is always (i=row, j=column)?

---

## Updated

With the answers from Akshay and @DaniMesejo, understood:

```
X[
  (4),    # dimension 2 indices with only 1 element
  (2)     # dimension 1 indices with only 1 element
] = 1

Y[
  (4, 2, ...), # dimension 2 indices 
  (5, 3, ...)  # dimension 1 indices (dimension 0 is e.g. np.array(3) whose shape is (), in my understanding)
] = 1
```

Comment: Is always `i = row` and `j = column`. Your interpretation is mistaken. In your first example the parenthesis are redundant (is the same as X[4, 2]). Where the 4 is the index of the first axis and 2 is the index of the second axis. So every value that is before the comma is for rows and the ones after are for columns. But the the thing is that you can pass multiple values for both rows and columns, like Y[(4, 2), (5, 3)], as said all the values before the comma are for the first axis and the one after the comma are for the second axis.

Comment: @DaniMesejo, thank you for pointing it out " values before the comma are for the first axis and the one after the comma are for the second axis". <-- I misunderstood this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy to understand how it works (and the motivation behind this design decision).

Numpy stores its ndarrays as contiguous blocks of memory. Each element is stored in a sequential manner every n bytes after the previous.

(images referenced from this [excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034237/how-does-numpys-transpose-method-permute-the-axes-of-an-array))

So if your 3D array looks like this  -

[image]

Then in memory its stores as -

[image]

When retrieving an element (or a block of elements), NumPy calculates how many `strides` (bytes) it needs to traverse to get the next element `in that direction/axis`. So, for the above example, for `axis=2` it has to traverse 8 bytes (depending on the `datatype`) but for `axis=1` it has to traverse `8*4` bytes, and `axis=0` it needs `8*8` bytes.

With this in mind, let's look at what you are trying to do.

```
print(X)
print(X.strides)
```

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]

#Strides (bytes) required to traverse in each axis.
(56, 8)
```

For your array, to get the next element in `axis=0`, we need to traverse `56 bytes`, and for the next element in `axis=1`, we need `8 bytes`.

When you are indexing `(4,2)`, NumPy is going `56*4` bytes in `axis=0` and `8*2` bytes in `axis=1` to access that. Similarly, if you want to access `(4,2)` and `(5,3)`, it will have to access `56*(4,5)` in `axis=0` and `8*(2,3)` in `axis=1`.

This is why the design is what it is because it aligns with how NumPy actually indexes elements using `strides`.

```
X[(axis0_indices), (axis1_indices), ..]

X[(4, 5), (2, 3)] #(row indices), (column indices)
```

```
array([1, 1])
```

With this design, it's easy to scale to higher dimension tensors (say, 8-dimensional arrays) as well! **If you were mentioning each index tuple separately, it will require elements * dimension number of computations to fetch those. While with this design, it can just broadcast the stride values to the tuple for each axis and fetch these much faster!**